Azure BLOB download yields 'Check internet connection' in browser
I am trying to enable a browser download functionality for Azure BLOB files.
The following code successfully finds the BLOB and is able to determine the length in bytes. However, when performing download, in the browser I can just see a message 'Check internet connection'. If I download in the background to the folder in the app and then from there to the browser, it works fine.  Any ideas what is going on?


public void DownloadFromAzureBLOB(string containerName, string blobName, HttpContext context, Page page)
{
    var response = page.Response;
    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING"));
    BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
    BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

    try
    {
        ServeBlobToClient(blobClient, blobName, response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response.Clear();
        response.Write($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
    }
}

private void ServeBlobToClient(BlobClient blobClient, string downloadFileName, HttpResponse response)
{
    try
    {
        BlobProperties properties = blobClient.GetProperties().Value;

        response.Clear();
        response.ClearHeaders();
        response.ClearContent();
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename={downloadFileName}");
        response.AddHeader("Content-Length", properties.ContentLength.ToString());
        response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
      
        using (var blobStream = blobClient.OpenRead())
        {
            // Stream the blob directly to the response output stream
            blobStream.CopyTo(response.OutputStream);
            response.Flush();
        }
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException($"Error streaming blob to client: {ex.Message}");
    }
}




The error is caused by the line of code: response.Flush();. After removing it, the problem was resolved.
